# resize a byte array in android

Tags: java, android

I am newbie in android.  I want to resize a byte array in function.  Is it possible or not.  If any problem please suggest a solution to do it.

```
public void myfunction(){
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    ....................
    .... do some operations........
    ................................
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2024];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
bytes = new byte[2024];
```

But your old content will be discarded.If you need the old data as well, then need to create a new byte  array with a diff size and call `System.arrayCopy()` method to copy data from old to new.

Answer (score 8):

To achieve the effect of resizing a byte array without loosing the content, there are several solutions in Java already mentioned:

**1)** `ArrayList<Byte>` (see the answers of a.ch. and kgiannakakis)

**2)** `System.arraycopy()` (see the answers of jimpic, kgiannakakis, and UVM)

Something like:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
//
// Do some operations with array bytes
//
byte[] bytes2 = new byte[2024];
System.arraycopy(bytes,0,bytes2,0,bytes.length);
//
// Do some further operations with array bytes2 which contains
// the same first 1024 bytes as array bytes
```

**3)** I would like to add a third way which I think is most elegant: `Arrays.copyOfRange()`

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
//
// Do some operations with array bytes
//
bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,0,2024);
//
// Do some further operations with array bytes whose first 1024 bytes
// didn't change and whose remaining bytes are padded with 0
```

Of course there are further solutions (e.g. copying the bytes in a loop). Concerning efficiency, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589741/how-to-effectively-copy-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

You can't resize an array in Java. You could use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to do what you want:

```
List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
```

Another way will be to use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). In that case you will create a second array and copy the content of the first array into it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. But you can create a new array and use System.arraycopy to copy the old contents to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ArrayList<Byte>` instead, Java arrays don't allow resizing, ArrayLists do, but make it a little bit different. You can't specify their size (actually you needn't - it is done automatically), you may specify initial capacity (which is good practice if you know how many elements will the `ArrayList` contain):

```
byte myByte = 0;
ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>(); //size is 0
ArrayList<Byte> bytes2 = new ArrayList<Byte>(1024); //initial capacity specified
bytes.add(myByte); //size is 1
...
```

I'd recommend you to look through this [Java Collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).