# What array copy method should I use?

Tags: java, arrays, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to effectively copy an array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589741/how-to-effectively-copy-an-array-in-java)

Is there a benefit to using `Arrays.copyOf()` or `System.arraycopy()`? Why should I use one or the other, and where?

Comment: A good reference question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589741/how-to-effectively-copy-an-array-in-java

Comment: ObFlippancy: Well `arraycopy` is a mess and isn't even capitalised correctly.

Comment: close this as a duplicate to the question Vulcan linked.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at these two links:

**[copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)**

**[arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)**

As vulcan suggested above, this explains it very nicely: [What is more efficient: System.arraycopy vs Arrays.copyOf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589741/how-to-effectively-copy-an-array-in-java)