# ArrayList method toArray in Java has @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation

Tags: java, generics

I was reading Effective Java by Josh Bloch and I came across an Item 24: Eliminate unchecked warnings.

In that they give an example of toArray() method of the class which generates unchecked warning.

```
    ArrayList.java:305: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
    found : Object[], required: T[]
    return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elements, size, a.getClass());
```

I am not bale to understand how the compiler is diagnosing that it would return Object[]?

May be I am not able to understand the type erasure phenomena behind it.

Can somebody explain me how Object[] would be returned?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the code that caused this warning to start?

Comment: Even the generic version has the annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checking its [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29) it clearly says that

```
public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original,
                           int newLength,
                           Class<? extends T[]> newType)
```

3rd argument specifies the **newType - the class of the copy to be returned**
and its `return` statement states 
:

```
Returns:
     a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with nulls to obtain the 
     specified length
```

check [this](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t87043.html) as well for `Object[]` return
and
[What is more efficient: System.arraycopy vs Arrays.copyOf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589741/how-to-effectively-copy-an-array-in-java)

**Edit:**
check for type erasure in oracle docs tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

it says:

Replace all **type parameters** (like T K V) in generic types with their bounds or `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

Comment: Still bit confused. But I am not able to get how Object[] is created ? Can you please explain me that.

Comment: I got it the copyOf method returns Object[] and not anything of type T[] and so is the warning.

Comment: @Sam was about to comment same thing check this for more info http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html