# Can't cast methods from a cloned array

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting, clone

I am trying to cast methods from a cloned array. However, I'm experiencing some issues.
Here's the code:

```
    Array1[] a = new Array1[] {
        "new Array1("exampletext", 0.5, 205)
    };

    Object[] o = a.clone();
    System.out.println(o[0].getSomething());
```

It works when I use the "original" object. I thought the cloned object was an exact copy.
Can anyone tell me whats going wrong there or give me some hints?

Edit: Okay, here's the real code ( I can't compile it as well tho! )

```
Drinks[] gtrk = new Drinks[] {

    new Drinks("Drink1",            0.90,      205,        0.5 ),
    new Drinks("Drink2",            0.90,      190,        0.5 ),
    new Drinks("Drink3",            0.70,      150,        0.5 ),
    new Drinks("Drink4",            20.50,     500,        2.0 ),
    new Drinks("Drink5",            28.70,     360,        1.5 ),
    new Drinks("Drink6",            6.90,      2500,       12.0 )

};

public void objectArrayTest() {

    Object[] o = gtrk.clone();
    System.out.println(o.getName());

}
```

Comment: this even won't compile cause `o` is Object[] so, object[0] is an `Object` and Object not have that method.

Comment: There's no cast in there. The code you've given can't compile (it contains an odd number of ", for a start) and you haven't told us what  Array1 is. Try posting real code.

Comment: You need reflection for that; or you need compilable code and a system compiler.

Comment: A `Drinks[]` is not an `Object[]`. And an array does not have a `getName()` method.

Comment: The getName() method is defined in another class. I thought Object would be the same as an array. Thanks for the help though, I'm gonna find a better solution then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code (its works perfectly) check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589741/how-to-effectively-copy-an-array-in-java):

```
class Drinks{
String name;
int i;
double d1,d2;

public Drinks(String name, double d1, int i,  double d2) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.i = i;
    this.d1 = d1;
    this.d2 = d2;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Drinks [name=" + name + ", i=" + i + ", d1=" + d1 + ", d2=" + d2 + 

"]";
    }
}

public class ArrayEg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drinks[] gtrk = new Drinks[] {
                new Drinks("Drink1",            0.90,      205,        0.5 ),
                new Drinks("Drink2",            0.90,      190,        0.5 ),
                new Drinks("Drink3",            0.70,      150,        0.5 ),
                new Drinks("Drink4",            20.50,     500,        2.0 ),
                new Drinks("Drink5",            28.70,     360,        1.5 ),
                new Drinks("Drink6",            6.90,      2500,       12.0 )
            };
        Object[] obj = new Object[gtrk.length];
        System.arraycopy(gtrk, 0, obj , 0, gtrk.length);
        for(Object o:obj){
            System.out.print((Drinks)o);    
        }
    }
}
```

In the case if you need call a some **method** from Drinks object, try with (inside the loop)

```
((Drinks)o).method
```