# Is there a way to instantiate a comparable array, just establishing its length

Tags: java, arrays, comparable

I need to "extract" if you will, one particular row of a multi array of comparables. I know the index of the row, I just need a copy of it. I tried just doing something like:

masterList is the multiarray that I need to extract from.

```
Comparable[] extracted = masterList[i];
```

This however only sets extracted to the address and not the actual contents.

Is there an easy way to do this?

If not can I create an empty Comparable[] of the same length as the masterList[i] row and loop through to add to it? Please note that my program doesn't start off knowing the length of the row it needs so I can't hard code it into the program.

Updated code:

```
    Comparable[][] comparable = Arrays.copyOf(masterList, masterList[i].length);
```

When I ran this I did get an array of the length I need but it was all addresses, not values. So I ran a loop to add the values

```
for(int i = 0; i<comparable.length; ++i){
        comparable[i] = queries[masterIndex];
    }
```

this however still returns a list of addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried System.arraycopy?

```
Comparable extracted[] = new Comparable[masterList[i].length]
System.arraycopy(masterList[i],0, extracted, 0, extracted.length);
```

This should make a shallow copy of the elements at masterList[i][j=0 to length-1] in `extracted`.

Please note that both of the solutions described here **will throw a NullPointerException** *if* `master list[i]` happens to be `null`. Be sure to check for that to avoid a nasty runtime surprise.

`System.arraycopy` is handy if you want to copy a part of the array. Here is a [good discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589741/what-is-more-efficient-system-arraycopy-vs-arrays-copyof) on both the approaches.

Hope this helps!

Comment: System.arrayCopy(masterList[i],extracted); is not being allowed. Says it's not valid for Comparable[]

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed that syntax after the first post, and just changed the "C" in copy to lowercase

Comment: Wow, that link you attached is Gold :)

Answer (score 3):

> If not can I create an empty Comparable[] of the same length as the masterList[i] row and loop through to add to it?

No need. You can just do

```
Comparable[] extracted = Arrays.copyOf(masterList[i], masterList[i].length);
```

> Please note that my program doesn't start off knowing the length of the row it needs so I can't hard code it into the program.

See, you need not to hard code the length as well.

Comment: @Suresh, you answer is more concise than mine. +1!

Comment: This seems like it should work, but when I try to print out the new extracted array it is still giving me a list of addresses not values?

Comment: Can you please update with your new code ?? Do not modify the current, just paste new code as an update or ask new question :)

Comment: @Read_My_Feels991 `Arrays.copyOf(masterList,` should be `Arrays.copyOf(masterList[i],`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--), because all arrays are [`Cloneable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html):

```
Comparable[] extracted = masterList[i].clone();
```

This will create a shallow copy of `masterList[i]` (if `masterList[i]` is `null`, you'll get a `NullPointerException`).